# How to Pass parameter to an action while opening a popup in Jquery

Tags: jquery

i have

```
public actionresult GAccess(String selectedIDs){
    //do some code witht he selected ids    
    return partialview("GAccess",model);
}

$("ownedButton").click function(){
    $("owneddialog").data("selectedIDs","1,2,3").dialog("open");
}

$("owneddialog").dialog({
    open:function(){    
        //I want to load the url with the parameter.  please suggest
    }
})
```

Comment: inside the open method: `$(this).data("selectedIDs")` will return the parameters you set

Comment: I want to pass like this

Comment: url = '@Url.Action("GAccess","controller", new{ selectedIDs = $(this.data("selectedIDs")}  but it is not accepting.

Comment: you are doing it wrong, not: `$(this.data("selectedIDs")` but: `$(this).data("selectedIDs")`, you are missing a ')'

Comment: that's a typo.  But it is not working even if we pass like $(this).load('@Url.Action("GAccess", "controller", new {selectedIds = $(this).data('selectedIDs')})');

Comment: are you getting the `selectedIDs`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your selector is correct, `$(this).data('selectedIDs')` should return the data. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kVLF/) demonstrates that it works. Maybe your problem is the `=` sign in the `new {selectedIDs = $(this).data('selectedIDs')}` bit? Shouldn't it be a `:`?

Comment: selector is correct and it is returning values, tested by placing the $(this).data('selectedIDs') in alert.